# Trying to understand why h:commandLink submits through validation and a4j:commandLink doesn't

Tags: jsf

First of all, i'm using Jsf 1.2...

I have a problem with submitting some values in a form to validation.
Specifically this code segement:

```
<h:panelGrid columns="4" id="StatusPanel">
    <h:outputText value="#{msg.Phone_number_to_send_SMS_to}" />
    <h:inputText id="phoneNumber" value="#{general.smsPhoneNumber}" required="true"
        requiredMessage="Please enter a valid phone number." />
    <a4j:commandLink value="#{msg.Submit_Button}"
        reRender="pinCodeDeliveryMsgText, pinCodeDeliveryMsg, pinCodeDeliveryFailedMsg, pinCodeDeliveryMainPanel, LastPinCodeMsg, SendingSMSMSG"
        action="#{general.submit}" />
        <h:message for="phoneNumber" fatalClass="mandatoryFieldMissing" errorClass="mandatoryFieldMissing" tooltip="true" />
</h:panelGrid>
```

Which looks like this in the html page:

[image]

Whenever I press the submit link, the page doesn't really go through validation, it seems to go with the last successull values instead. The result being that, if the phone number field is left empty, it does nothing and doesn't even render the `<h:message>` tag.

Actually, I have a workaround fix that looks like this:

```
<h:commandLink value="#{msg.Submit_Button}">
    <a4j:support event="onclick" reRender="pinCodeDeliveryMsgText, pinCodeDeliveryMsg, pinCodeDeliveryFailedMsg, pinCodeDeliveryMainPanel, LastPinCodeMsg, SendingSMSMSG"
    action="#{general.submit}"/>
</h:commandLink>
```

But i'm really curious to know what's the difference between `a4j:commandLink` and `h:commandLink` that makes one woirk and the other not.

TnX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to set the process attribute of a4j:commandLink to the id of the inputText? Looks like you are just triggering rerendering of some components, so no model update is performed at all.

Comment: Do i really have to explicitly write the id of every component I want to be validated? Seems like the wrong way to do it..

Comment: That is exactly the point. :-) 
For an asynchronous request you have to explicitly define which components should be processed (including validation) and which ones should only be rerendered. Use postback if you want to process and render everything on the page. 
The concept is briefly descibed here: http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html_single/#process